# Flutter web app is returning blank page after being deployed to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I have successfully deployed my flutter web app to Firebase hosting. However when I visit link blank page Is returned
Here is my firebase.json

```
    {
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new soicial network.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="lycread">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

  <title>LycRead Web</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=2330050811');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "my config",
      authDomain: "my config",
      projectId: "my config",
      storageBucket: "my config",
      messagingSenderId: "my config",
      appId: "my config",
      measurementId: "my config"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also when I open index.html with Chrome it also returns blank page. However when i run project with console everything is ok.

Here is my terminal output after deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem
It was in index.html
This part of code

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=2330050811');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

should come at the end of body tag

Answer (score 1):

The above answer was helpful.
you need to run  $flutter build web
then deploy again, open in private mode.

I hope this will help someone else as I tried it before a couple of days and appeared not to work for me.
the trick is to open page source to ensure change is really deployed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32746716)