# Blank page showing after succesful firebase deploy flutter web app

Tags: firebase, flutter, hosting

So I went through the whole firebase init process and a public folder was created with an index.html which I deleted and changed the firebase.json to match my index.html inside the flutter web folder. When I open the app it is a blank page but the flutter favicon and when I open dev tools is shows the correct index.html. I read a couple of posts that didn't exactly do the trick
or executed their solutions poorly. Either way due to the first post I tried deploying with

```
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF>
<base href="https://project_name.firebaseapp.com/">
<base href="https://project_name.web.app/">
<base href="/">
no href
```

and as for the second post, I swapped the to before the service worker script

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBn4vWGi9uYUW6nDLFm_mJ9m6ipkkKpyJg"></script>
```

Here's my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF"-->
<base href="https://project-name.firebaseapp.com/">


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

<!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="app">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

<title>app</title>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
    application. For more information, see:
    https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase.js"></script>-->

<script>
    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ":]",
    authDomain: "project-name.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "project-name",
    storageBucket: "project-name.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: ":]",
    appId: ":]",
    measurementId: ":]"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBn4vWGi9uYUW6nDLFm_mJ9m6ipkkKpyJg"></script>

<script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
    if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    scriptLoaded = true;
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
    scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
    document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // Service workers are supported. Use them.
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
        .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
            serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                loadMainDartJs();
                }
            });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
            // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
            // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
            waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
            // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
            // need to ask the service worker to update.
            console.log('New service worker available.');
            reg.update();
            waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
            // Existing service worker is still good.
            console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
            loadMainDartJs();
            }
        });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
        if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
            'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
        }
        }, 4000);
    });
    } else {
    // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
    loadMainDartJs();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "app/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my website
[image: my website]

LINKS Here:

https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/1U9HnWlG4q4

[Flutter web app is returning blank page after being deployed to firebase hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321343/flutter-web-app-is-returning-blank-page-after-being-deployed-to-firebase-hosting)

Any help is appreciated, and thank you for taking the time to do so!